# Loop in Spring Controller Method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have some very strange behaviour in one of my spring controller which I can not explain.

So this is what I have. Very simple controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/doSomething")
public void doSomething(@RequestParam int value, HttpSession session) {

    System.out.println("Lorem");

    // Some stuff later on done here

    System.out.println("ipsum");

}
```

When I request the mapped URL the controller behaves as it whould have an infiniate loop inside. So it starts with the output "Lorem" then "ipsum" and instead of leaving the method it starts right from the beginning of the method again. It is not called multiple times from external. Does anybody know this behaviour or has any clue? Furthermore I could observe that the output speed slows down as memory drastically increases up to about 1.5 GB and 100% CPU usage spread all over every single core.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handler method doesn't seem right to me. Typically you need to return a string that will be resolved into a View by ViewResolver, eg:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/doSomething")
public String doSomething(@RequestParam int value, HttpSession session) {
   // ....
  return "somethingdone";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't need to tell spring to load any specific view, as I just use the controller to do some stuff. The method is called asynchronous from a normal html page with jQuery. So in some other cases I used @ResponseBody to get a JSON encoded response but in this case I just don't need any response.

Comment: Just tried it in with @ResponseBody void but with the same result. Funny thing is that I have another method in the same controller where it works just fine.

Comment: Check your MVC configuration, maybe /doSomething is mapped as an error handler, hence when exception occured it goes back there (infinite loop).

Comment: No, sorry. It is not defined as error page or somewhere else. Also tried with different mappings.

Comment: Well it realy seams, that Spring does not allow and empty resposne. It seams to work with @ResponseBody String. Thanks.

Comment: @Ralf If the handler returns void spring expects you to write directly to the response yourself. You could inject `HttpServletResponse` as an argument and write to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding.

If a controller declares a void return type  , Spring will attempt to infer the view name from the request URL.

In your case, it will assume the view name is "doSomething", and proceed on that assumption.

It does this using an implementation of RequestToViewNameTranslator, The default  implementation of RequestToViewNameTranslator is DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator

See [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator.html)